# Bad configuration option: GlobalKnownHostsFile

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-buster

My sshd refuses to start when I set the option GlobalKnownHostsFile.

When I run `/usr/sbin/sshd -T` it says *“Bad configuration option: GlobalKnownHostsFile”*.

Any ideas why this happens? According to [the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html), this is a valid configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It’s a client option and therefore it belongs in the client config (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) and not in the daemon config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config).